# Rails app title displays on localhost, not online

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, heroku, title

I have made a web app based off [the tutorial by Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org), and the title tags all work on my localhost (after running `rails console`), but when I put it online ([here](http://shoulakpredictions.com)), the titles don't display. It defaults to the titles by hover ("Domains Made Simple").

My app is hosted through Heroku.

---

Edit 1

---

Here is my `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Edit 2

---

Here is the `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` that contains the `full_title` method:

```
module ApplicationHelper     
  def full_title(page_title)  
    base_title = "Shoulak Predictions"  
    if page_title.empty?  
      base_title  
    else  
      "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"  
    end
  end
end
```

---

Edit 3

---

### Update

Off a hunch, and based off the comment by Alen, I changed the beginning of my `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` to be `<title>Shoulak Predictions</title>`. It is still overridden by Hover's "Domains Made Simple".

Comment: Can you post your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`?

Comment: Your title tag is the problem here.

Comment: Why don't you define instance variable in your controllers `@title = "string"`. Variable will be available automatically in each corresponding view. Then just output via `<%= @title %>`.

Comment: @Alen Because I want to have dynamic titles based off the web page.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your domain provider actually hosts its own webpage at your domain, and puts your website in a frameset. You should instead point your domain at your Heroku app, as described in [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains).

Comment: I thought I had to manage my DNS through hover? That's where I got lost in the guide.